# How to properly throw rxjs exception?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There is stream event click:

```
this.markAsReadClick
            .pipe(
                concatMap(() =>
                    this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsReestrIds$.pipe(
                        take(1),
                        tap((ids: number[]) => {
                            if (!ids.length) throw throwError('Error');
                        }),
                      
                        concatMap((ids: number[]) => ...
```

trying to throw an exception to prevent concatMap from executing:

```
if (! ids.length) throw throwError ('Error');
```

When an error occurs - `this.markAsReadClick` is terminated. How to avoid this?

**Full code is:**

```
this.markAsReadClick
            .pipe(
                concatMap(() =>
                    this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsReestrIds$.pipe(
                        take(1),
                        tap((ids: number[]) => {
                            if (!ids.length) throw throwError('Err');
                        }),
                        indicate(this.markAsReadloading$),
                        concatMap((ids: number[]) =>
                            this.confirmDialogsService.open({ title: 'Подтверждение операции', text: 'Вы уверены?' }).pipe(
                                filter(Boolean),
                                concatMap(() =>
                                    this.documentsRepository.markAsPrinted(ids).pipe(
                                        handleResponseMessage(this.messageService),
                                        catchError((error) => of(error)),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                catchError((error) => of(error)),
            )

            .subscribe((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                if (response instanceof Error) {
                    this.messageService.showMessage('', response.message, 'warning');
                    return;
                }
                this.router.navigate(['documents'], { queryParams: { t: new Date().getTime() } });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`throwError` is a regular Error wrapped with an Observable, designed for operators that should return ObservableLike values (e.g. `switchMap`,`contactMap`, etc.), for `tap` operator you should throw a regular Error rather than an Observable:

```
tap((ids: number[]) => {
   if (!ids.length) throw new Error('Err');
}),
```

Having thrown an error within `contactMap` (inner stream) you should handle it in there (using [`cathError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError)) to avoid outer stream termination:

```
concatMap(() =>
  this.documentsRepository.selectedDocumentsReestrIds$.pipe(
    take(1),
    tap((ids: number[]) => {
      if (!ids.length) throw throwError('Err');
    }),
    indicate(this.markAsReadloading$),
    concatMap((ids: number[]) =>
        ...
    ),
    catchError(x => of(x) // <== handle inner stream errors
  )
)
```